# What does the expression `rails db <` mean?

Tags: unix

I use the command `rails db < dbfile.sql`. But I do not quite understand it. It's hard to search by google with the operator `<`.

Does anyone know about it or can anyone give me a link to a document?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-io-redirections.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<` is a unix redirection operator. It redirects standard input to be read from `dbfile.sql` in your example.

`rails db < dbfile.sql` means redirect the contents of `dbfile.sql` to the `rails db` command (which is to open the database console), which executes the SQL in the DB.

Look at Redirection Operators in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514).